# Get true timestamps of motion sensors on Android

Tags: android, tango, arcore

It is known that readings of motion sensors are cached on queues, so there might be elapsed time between when the data are actually sampled and when they are popped from the queue. Is the `timestamp` member in `SensorEvent` the time when the data are sampled? According to the documentation in [SensorEvent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html), it is probably not. Is there a way to measure the "true" timestamp at which the data are sampled? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SensorEvent.timestamp` is the time [at which the event happened](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html#timestamp), or in other words, the time [at which the data is generated](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html#sensors-monitor).  This is the most accurate timestamp value available, and the value you should use as the "true" timestamp for when the data was sampled in your calculations.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is there a "standard" way to get the timestamp at which the image was captured?